# Search api autocomplete - how to show search form?

Tags: search

I use Search Api with Search api autocomplete module.

I made configuration of autocomplete module on Search Api page, but I do not see block for input.

Should I config anything else for it?

Answer (score 1):

There should be a block named Search box in admin/structure/block, i think it is the search box by default of drupal.

Remember that this block uses a view that returns a JSON, you can specify which view to use entering admin/config/search/search_autocomplete

Comment: Standard search block does not have possibility to autocomplite. This feature appears if I use exposed filter in Views (by index). I also want to use Views to make autocomlite more attractive (put their picture and some information) - in Autocomplite settings there is Views selection - but only Master, Page or Block. How to specify Views name to use?

Comment: Edit the view `nodes_autocomplete` (I think it comes with the autocomplete module) if not, create a new one of Content, with Format: Autocomplete JSON, add some fields, in format json settings, configure the label, link, and output fields you want to show etc. And then configure the view to use in `/admin/config/search/search_autocomplete/3/config`